# Group send a channel layer from outside consumer class

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have a process that when it gets a message it sends a command to a celery process.
From there I would want to send back a message from the celery worker back to the backend telling it "Im done now you can continue".
So can I send a group message to a channel layer from outside

edit should probably add some code example also:

**consumer.py**

```py
async def startGame(self):
    if self.leader:
        songList = await self.getSongs()
        await self.downloadSongs(songList)
```

**tasks.py**

```py
@shared_task
def downloadSongs(songList, room_group_name):
    from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
    print(room_group_name)
    for song in songList:
        if not os.path.isfile("./songfiles/" + song["song_id"] + ".mp3"):
            print("Downloading song: " + song["title"])
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    print(channel_layer)
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'startGameGroup',
        })
    print("Done sleeping")
```

**consumer.py**

```py
async def startGameGroup(self, event):
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        "ContentType": "startGameGroup",
    }))
```

so when startGame in consumer run it calls a celery task called downloadSongs. From there it should send back a message to the backend saying that it is done and it can start the game

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note when you have this error, you cant have channel layer set to InMemoryChannel, I would recommend using redis instead, this fixed my issues

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).